# What is the purpose of a class inheriting a Generic in python?

Tags: python, python-typing

What's the difference between these two codes?

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
from logging import Logger

T = TypeVar('T')

class LoggedVar(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, value: T, name: str, logger: Logger) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.logger = logger
        self.value = value
```

and

```py
from typing import TypeVar
from logging import Logger

T = TypeVar('T')

class LoggedVar:
    def __init__(self, value: T, name: str, logger: Logger) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.logger = logger
        self.value = value
```

I couldn't understand what's so special of having Generic as the base class of LoggedVar. Can anyone please explain it to me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version is a generic class. `LoggedVar[int]` is a specialization of the class, that takes an `int` as the `value` argument in its constructor. If there were any other uses of `T` in the class, the value of `T` would have to match.

The second version is a non-generic class with a generic `__init__` method. `T` will be deduced to different things depending on what `value` you pass, but there is no way to declare specializations of the class like `LoggedVar[int]`, and if other methods used `T`, those would be separate generic methods, with no requirement that `T` match whatever was deduced for `__init__`.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give me an example of LoggedVar[int]? I don't really get when you said specialization of the class.

Comment: @Blodstone: `x: LoggedVar[int] = LoggedVar[int](1, 'a', some_logger)`